# Showing this set is not complete (logic)?

Tags: logic

I want to show that the set $\{\wedge, \top, \bot\}$ is not complete. I can't quite figure out a wff that cannot be expressed using just these three. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How about the wtf $\lnot x$? Show by induction that all wff are 'non increasing' in terms of the constituent variables.e

Comment: A wff in what language? How about $x \vee y$, with $x$ and $y$ as sentential variables?

Comment: The wff is in sentential logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: You know that $\{\wedge, \neg\}$ *is* complete, and clearly $\wedge$ is expressible by your set (since it contains $\wedge$ already); so what's a wff $\mathcal{W}$ that *has* to be inexpressible by your set, if your set is to be incomplete?

Now to *show* this, you're going to have to use induction on formula complexity; and the easiest way to do this is to classify exactly what connectives in the "right" number of variables (that is: as many variables as are in $\mathcal{W}$) are expressible by your set. So try a few combinations; what connectives does it look like you can build?